# How to use after and each in conjunction to create a synchronous loop in underscore js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, each, synchronous

Hi I'm trying to create a synchronous loop using underscore js. For each loop iteration I make some further asynchronous calls. However, I need to wait until each iteration call is finished before I move on to the next iteration.

Is this possible in underscore js ? If yes, how so ? could someone please provide an example ?

```
_.( items ).each( function(item) {

      // make aync call and wait till done
      processItem(item, function callBack(data, err){
            // success. ready to move to the next item.
      });
      // need to wait till processItem is done.

 });
```

**UPDATE**
I solved this using the async.eachSeries method.

```
 async.eachSeries( items, function( item, callback){
      processItem(item, function callBack(data, err){

            // Do the processing....

            // success. ready to move to the next item.
            callback(); // the callback is used to flag success 
                        // andgo back to the next iteration
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a synchronous looping construct such as underscore's `.each()` because it won't wait for the async operations to be completed before going to the next iteration and it can't be made to do so in a single threaded world like Javascript.

You will have to use a looping construct that specifically supports async operations. There are many to choose from - you can build your own pretty easily or use the async library in node.js or let promises sequence things for you. Here's an article about some async control in underscore: daemon.co.za/2012/04/simple-async-with-only-underscore.

Here's one common design pattern I use:

```
function processData(items) {
    // works when items is an array-like data structure
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < items.length) {
            // note, I switched the order of the arguments to your callback to be more "node-like"
            processItem(items[index], function(err, data) {
                // error handling goes here
                ++index;
                next();
            }
        }
    }
    // start the first iteration
    next();
}
```

---

For pre-built libraries for node.js, the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) is quite often used for this.  It has async-capable versions of many of the popular methods for iterating collections such a `.map()`, `.each()`, `.reduce()`, etc...  In your case, I think you'd be looking for [`.eachSeries()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) to force the async operations to run one after another (and not in parallel).

---

For using promises, the [Bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) has an async capable `.each()` that calls the next iteration when a promise is resolved allowing you to use async operations in the iterator, but maintain sequential execution.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, I'll look into the promise library. For now I have solved it using async.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your question: No, this cannot be done with underscore. All the items will be processed and you have no way to process the array as a serie.

you probably want to look at something like [async/mapSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapSeries)